# How to adjust contrast with xcalib

Tags: xorg, brightness, xrandr, xcalib

I'm trying to adjust contrast on my laptop, a **ThinkPad E430**, running ubuntu 12.04:

```
xcalib -co 70 -a
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.7
```

Either of them works only for 1-2 seconds and after that contrast drops to its normal setting by Ubuntu. What should I do to prevent this action?

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer to help others and show that this question has been solved

Comment: @minerz029 why do you think they solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround that achieves the same goal:

```
xbacklight -set 77
redshift -t 6100:6100 -g 0.8:0.8:0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with xcalib only working for 1-2 seconds, and in my case the problem was that I was already running redshift, which repeatedly sets the color settings to what it wants.

After I stopped redshift, xcalib worked as intended.